# Editing subrow - jquery easyui edatagrid

Tags: edit, jquery-easyui, subgrid

OK- I have been beating my head against this since last Friday, I figure it is finally time to post for help. I think I have my code fairly settled, and I think things should work.

I have a grid where I edit the row, add rows, and then I expand the rows loading a subgrid (editable edatagrid). I want to simply edit and cancel the editable subgrid. However also want to take the ID column that I pass to the server page for updating from the parent row (api).

Editing and adding new rows is working, opening the fields I want as editable in an editable grid in the sub row is working. However getting the sub grid to cancel edit, save, and use iconCls will not work (iconCls code removed at the moment for the subgrid). I have not included all the code, just what is relevant to the question here so there are some other calls with missing javascript. If anybody would like that code just holler, and I will include it.

master grid

```
<section class="grid">     
  <table id="wells" class="easyui-datagrid" title=" " style="width:100%;height:500px"
        pagination="true" idField="api" fitColumns="true" url="getinfo.php"
        collapsible="true" singleSelect="true" toolbar="#tb" resizeHandle="both"
        autoRowHeight="true" nowrap="false" rownumbers="true" pageList="[10,25,50,100,5000]">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th data-options="field:'well_name', width:48" sortable="true">Name</th>
                <th data-options="field:'well_num',width:18" sortable="true">Num</th>
                <th data-options="field:'field',width:48" sortable="true">Field</th>
                <th data-options="field:'pad',width:36" sortable="true">Pad</th>
                <th data-options="field:'api',width:32" sortable="true">API</th>
                <th data-options="field:'legal_description',width:46" sortable="true">Legal</th>
                <th data-options="field:'county_state',width:40" sortable="true">County, State</th>
                <th data-options="field:'lease',width:33" sortable="true">Lease</th>
                <th data-options="field:'unit_ca_pa',width:57" sortable="true">Unit CA PA</th>
                <th data-options="field:'status',width:27">Status</th>
                <th data-options="field:'status_date',width:22">Updated</th>
                <th data-options="field:'wildlife_stips',width:75">Wildlife Stips</th>
                <th data-options="field:'notes',width:75">Notes</th>                                
            </tr>
        </thead>
  </table>
```

master grid toolbar

```
  <div id="tb" style="padding:3px"><span>Field:</span>
      <input id="field" style="line-height:22px;border:1px solid #ccc">
        <span>Pad:</span>
        <input id="pad" style="line-height:22px;border:1px solid #ccc">
        <span>API:</span>
        <input id="api" style="line-height:22px;border:1px solid #ccc">
        <a href="#" class="easyui-linkbutton" plain="true" onclick="doSearch()">Search</a>
        <a href="#" class="easyui-linkbutton" plain="true" onclick="doReset()">Reset</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="easyui-linkbutton" iconCls="icon-add" plain="true" onclick="newWell()">New Well</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="easyui-linkbutton" iconCls="icon-edit" plain="true" onclick="editWell()">Edit Well</a>
  </div>
```

expandable, edatagrid section

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#wells').datagrid(
        {
            view: detailview,
            detailFormatter:function(index,row)
            { return '<div style="padding:2px"><table class="ddv"></table></div>'; },
                onExpandRow: function(index,row)
                {
                    var ddv = $(this).datagrid('getRowDetail',index).find('table.ddv');
                    ddv.edatagrid(
                    {
                        url:'geteditexpand.php?api='+row.api,
                        saveUrl:'updateeditwell.php?api='+row.api,
                        fitColumns:true,
                        singleSelect:true,
                        rownumbers:true,
                        loadMsg:'',
                        height:'auto',
                        columns:[[
                            {field:'location',title:'Location'},
                            {field:'NorthSouth',title:'N+S-',editor:'text'},
                            {field:'EastWest',title:'E+W-',editor:'text'},
                            {field:'latitude',title:'Latitude',editor:'text'},
                            {field:'longitude',title:'Longitude',editor:'text'},
                            {field:'lot',title:'Lot',editor:'text'},
                            {field:'tract',title:'Tract',editor:'text'},
                            {field: 'action', title: 'Action',
                                 formatter:function(value,row,index)
                                 {
                                    var s = '<a href="#" onclick="javascript:$(#wells).edatagrid(saveRow)">Save</a> ';
                                    var c = '<a href="#" onclick="javascript:$(#wells).edatagrid(cancelRow)">Cancel</a>';
                                    return s+c;
                                }
                            }
                        ]],
                        onResize:function()
                        { $('#wells').edatagrid('fixDetailRowHeight',index); },
                        onLoadSuccess:function()
                        {
                            setTimeout(function(){
                            $('#wells').edatagrid('fixDetailRowHeight',index);
                        },0);
                    }
                });
                $('#wells').datagrid('fixDetailRowHeight',index);
            }   
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

you dont have updateURL, im not sure

url(source)
saveUrl(NewRecord)

missing
updateUrl:'updatefile.php'